# Add to the drop-down list the ability to select an element

Tags: javascript, html, css

I wrote a drop-down list function, where there are three `<a>` elements; how do I add the ability to select from among `<a>` so that the selected element is displayed as active instead of button?

```js
function dropdownMenu() {
  document.getElementById("myDropdown").classList.toggle("show");
}
window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (!event.target.matches('.dropbtn')) {
    let dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-content");
    for (let i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; i++) {
      let openDropdown = dropdowns[i];
      if (openDropdown.classList.contains('show')) {
        openDropdown.classList.remove('show');
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```css
.dropbtn {
  background: #F0F0F0;
  width: 262px;
  height: 40px;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-family: 'Inter';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 100%;
  margin-left: 23px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.dropbtn:hover {
  background-color: #979797;
  transition: all ease 0.4s;
}

.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  width: 262px;
  height: 132px;
  position: absolute;
  background: #FFFFFF;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  z-index: 1;
  font-family: 'Inter';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 100%;
  margin-left: 23px;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  color: black;
  padding: 15px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: #FAFAFA;
}

.show {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="dropdownMenu()" class="dropbtn">ACTIVE</button>
<div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content">
  <a href="#">ONE</a>
  <a href="#">TWO</a>
  <a href="#">THREE</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the select element.

**EDIT1**

Select options cannot have many styles, so we need to implement it using other elements:

```js
function dropdownMenu() {
  document.getElementById("myDropdown").classList.toggle("show");
}

window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (event.target.matches('#myDropdown a')) {
    myDropdown.classList.remove('show');
    
    document.querySelector('.dropbtn').innerText = event.target.innerText; //get the selected text!
  }
}
```

```css
.dropbtn {
  background: #F0F0F0;
  width: 262px;
  height: 40px;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-family: 'Inter';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 100%;
  margin-left: 23px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.dropbtn:hover {
  background-color: #979797;
  transition: all ease 0.4s;
}
.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}
.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  width: 262px;
  height: 132px;
  position: absolute;
  background: #FFFFFF;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  z-index: 1;
  font-family: 'Inter';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 100%;
  margin-left: 23px;
}
.dropdown-content a {
  color: black;
  padding: 15px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}
.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: #FAFAFA;
}
.show {
  display:block;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="dropdownMenu()" class="dropbtn">ACTIVE</button>
  <div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content">
    <a href="#">ONE</a>
    <a href="#">TWO</a>
    <a href="#">THREE</a>
  </div>
```

Comment: I have styles that will disappear on a normal select, is it possible to rewrite exactly according to my function like that?

Comment: This is important. Can you update the question with those styles? I'll try to make them work.

Comment: added all styles to the question

Comment: Right, I'll dig into it.